# Retrieving URL from blob search API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Following the documentation for GitLab's Search API here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/search.html#scope-blobs I was wondering if there was a way to generate a clickable URL to the file/blob in question, preferably with the line number included.

Given the response, it's possible to manually navigate to the path and line in question with the project id, but it doesn't seem to be possible to take the blob ref and/or path and automatically generate the url.

Some background on what I'm trying to do is automate a GitLab search for reporting purposes